# Is there a way to pick what is marked as required on lightning-input-address form?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

Looking off of the documentation of [lightning-input-address](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-address/example) I see that when you mark it as required, everything but country is marked as required. Is there a way to pick and choose what you want as required in it? In the documentation it just states for validating required fields, but nothing else.

Was curious, because lets say I wanted to have Country and State(province) marked as required, but not City. Then how would I do that or if it is even possible with LWC.

Comment: I think you have to go for custom lightning-input fields for that.

Comment: That's what I was thinking originally, but then I wouldn't be able to utilize the show-address-lookup feature lightning-input-address provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug to me, wherein only country is not marked required.

But if you want to mark only some fields required from the address component, you can remove the `required` attribute from the  `lightning-input-address component` in `html` file and instead use `setCustomValidityForField` method in the JS. You can find the documentation of this method in the [lightning-input-address](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-address/specification) specification

Below code sample shows how to validate only country and state fields

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const address = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-address');
    //Country Field Validation
    var country = address.country;
    if (!country) {
        address.setCustomValidityForField('Field is Required', 'country');
    } else {
        address.setCustomValidityForField("", 'country'); //Reset previously set message
    }

    //State Field Validation
    var province = address.province;
    if (!province) {
        address.setCustomValidityForField('Field is Required', 'province');
    } else {
        address.setCustomValidityForField("", 'province'); //Reset previously set message
    }
    address.reportValidity(); // Refreshes the component to show or remove error messages from UI
    const isValid = address.checkValidity(); //Check if the address is Valid and accordingly proceed.
    
}
```

The only drawback here is, the asterisk sign won't appear. You will have to fiddle with `css` a bit to achieve that.